# ref.listen method doesn't call one that is given as a parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I use Riverpod for state management

I'd like to observe a String message which is shared by a `StateNotifier<LoginNotifierData>`. I call `ref.listen` in a `ConsumerState<LoginScreen>`. But although `state.message` is being changed, the Function in `ref.listen` is not called. My question is why the function which is given as the second parameter for `ref.listen()` is not called when the `state` is being changed.

I use Equatable library to compare objects

When I observe the whole LoginNotifierData object (without `loginModelStateNotifierProvider.select()`) it also doesn't work

login method in Notifier (it changes the `state`):

```
void login(String username, String password, WidgetRef ref) async {
    state.message = "Logowanie...";
    Either<Failure, LoginModel> setLogin = await ref
        .read(loginUseCaseProvider)
        .call(LoginParams(
        username: username,
        password: password));
    setLogin.fold((failure) {
      log('API Login: failure');
      state.message = failure.message;
      log(failure.toString());
    }, (loginModel) {
      log('API Login: success=${loginModel.success}');
      if (loginModel.success) {
        ref
            .read(loginModelStateNotifierProvider.notifier)
            .setLoginModel(loginModel);
        _storeUserData(loginModel, ref);
        ref.read(userRepositoryProvider).storeUsername(username);
        ref.read(userRepositoryProvider).storePassword(password);
        state.message = "";
      } else {
        state.message = loginModel.message;
        log('responseCode: ${loginModel.responseCode}');
      }
    });

  }
```

LoginNotifierData (the `state` is of this type)

```
class LoginNotifierData extends Equatable {
  LoginModel loginModel = LoginModel("", 0, "", false, "", "", "", false, 0.0, "", "");
  String message = "";

  LoginNotifierData(this.loginModel, this.message);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [loginModel, message];
}
```

ref.listen called in `@override Widget build` method in a ConsumerState

```
ref.listen<String>(
        loginModelStateNotifierProvider.select((value) => value.message),
            (_, message) {
          if(message.isNotEmpty) {
            widget.showLoaderDialog(context, message);
          } else {
            widget.hideDialog();
          }
        }
    );
```

loginModelStateNotifierProvider:

```
final loginModelStateNotifierProvider =
StateNotifierProvider<LoginModelStateNotifier, LoginNotifierData>(
        (ref) => LoginModelStateNotifier()
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the a `state` by re-assigning properties in a `StateNotifier`...You have to re-assign the `state` itself.

Using `copyWith` method allows you to do this.

Follow these steps:

***1. Create a `copyWith` method in `LoginNotifierData`***

```
class LoginNotifierData extends Equatable {
  LoginModel loginModel = LoginModel("", 0, "", false, "", "", "", false, 0.0, "", "");
  String message = "";

  LoginNotifierData(this.loginModel, this.message);

  LoginNotifierData copyWith({LoginModel? loginModel, String? message}){
     return LoginNotifierData(
        loginModel: loginModel,
        message: message,
     );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [loginModel, message];
}
```

***2. Use the copy with method to re-assign the state in the StateNotifier***

```
void login(String username, String password, WidgetRef ref) async {
    state = state.copyWith(message: "Logowanie...");
    Either<Failure, LoginModel> setLogin = await ref
        .read(loginUseCaseProvider)
        .call(LoginParams(
        username: username,
        password: password));
    setLogin.fold((failure) {
      log('API Login: failure');
      state = state.copyWith(message: failure.message);
      log(failure.toString());
    }, (loginModel) {
      log('API Login: success=${loginModel.success}');
      if (loginModel.success) {
        ref
            .read(loginModelStateNotifierProvider.notifier)
            .setLoginModel(loginModel);
        _storeUserData(loginModel, ref);
        ref.read(userRepositoryProvider).storeUsername(username);
        ref.read(userRepositoryProvider).storePassword(password);
        state = state.copyWith(message: "");
      } else {
        state = state.copyWith(message: loginModel.message);
        log('responseCode: ${loginModel.responseCode}');
      }
    });

  }
```